# In focframwork GUI Table, some cells appear empty untill I open a row for edit and get back. Due to "maxCharaters" attribute

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-framework/framework).

My form layout in XML contains a table. The items appear normally until I add in one of the columns the attribute **maxCharacters="120"**. Then all cells on the first landing scroll page appear empty. They reappear when I open a details form and get back to the table form again.

```
<GuiTable name="COMPLAINT_HOTLINE_TABLE" dataPath="DATAROOT" width="100%">
  <TableColumn name="CODE" caption="Code" link="true" width="-1px"/>
  <TableColumn name="DATE" caption="Date" width="-1px"/>
  <TableColumn name="SUBJECT" caption="Subject" maxCharacters="120" width="350px"/>
</GuiTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. It is somehow due to the fact that the size of the cells with maxCharaters are not predetermined.

Anyway there is a workaround for it. In your Form's java class (if you didn't need one till now create one that extends **FocXMLLayout**) you need to override the **showValidationLayout** method and call the **re_parseXMLAndBuildGui**

```
@Override
public void showValidationLayout(boolean showBackButton) {
    super.showValidationLayout(showBackButton);
    re_parseXMLAndBuildGui();
}
```

As you may guess this will re-parse the whole XML file and build your form again. The work around is harsh but works fine. Maybe when we upgrade the a more recent vaadin version this will go away.